# How do I lazy load an external module from node_modules?

Tags: angular

We can lazy load a local module like this module

```js
    {
        path: 'somePpath',
        loadChildren: 'app/path/some.module#SomeModule'
    },
```

How do we lazy load a module that comes from an external library resides in node_modules?

Comment: what loader do you use?

Comment: Just tried it with angular-cli and `loadChildren: '../../node_modules/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'`. It works for me

Comment: @yurzui The context of *"external library"* almost certainly means exactly that and **not** an `NgModule` that we know works. So where the OP is asking to "lazy load a library" ( i.e lodash ), then that is just not what the feature here is about.

Comment: @NeilLunn OP wrote `How do we lazy load a **module** So i suggested he asked for NgModule

Comment: Maybe this issue will help you out: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6373

Answer (score 11):

To load an external module in the router module you might need to use a Wrapper module. Create a wrapper module in the same local project in which you are having your routing module. Import your external module in this wrapper module with traditional import syntax.

```js
import { SomeModule } from '@externalLib';
```

Include this module in the imports of `NgModule`'s import array.

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [SomeModule]
})
export class SomeWrapperModule {
}
```

Then use this wrapper module in the router module as we usually use a module.

```js
// for Angular 7 and below 
{
    path: 'some-path',
    loadChildren: '../somewrapper.module#SomeWrapperModule'
}

// for Angular 8+
{
    path: 'some-path',
    loadChildren: () => import('../somewrapper.module').then(mod => mod.SomeWrapperModule)
}
```

Comment: I can confirm this approach of using a WrapperModule works - but with a caveat. If you are trying to import more than one module into the wrapper module, it will not work. You need to create a wrapper module for each external library you want to lazy load.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure since which version, but at least since version 13 you can lazy load a node module anywhere directly in a method.

I use it, for example, when exporting data to excel, which is rarely run. Example:

```js
public export(): void {
    import('xlsx').then(xlsx => {
        xlsx.writeFile(...);
    });
}
```

Comment: The problem is, when you try to load a feature module lazily i.e. `SomeModule` from 'some-lib' and use some components from that module like: `<some-comp></some-comp>`, you cannot just run `import('some-lib').then()` to use the components you want.

Comment: It's now possible in Angular 17 with Deferrable Views. See more info in https://angular.io/guide/defer, or https://netbasal.com/a-comprehensive-guide-to-angulars-defer-block-468c74048df4.

Answer (score 0):

I have found other ways instead of creating a wrapper module which by the way is not very pleasant, follow below some more fancy approaches:

https://habr.com/en/post/442370/