# I want to lazy load my third party libraries?

Tags: angular, angular-lazyloading

I am trying to lazy load the third-party libraries but I couldn't find any solution if anyone have any idea please share.

Comment: do you mean something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44024823/how-do-i-lazy-load-an-external-module-from-node-modules ? Is it a route?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It’s very easy just add import followed by the relative path to 3rd party library (resided in `assests` folder) & rest of the thing will be done by `Angular CLI`.

**thirdParty.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';    
import '../../../../assets/3rd_Party_library.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-thirdParty',
  templateUrl: './thirdParty.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./thirdParty.component.css']
})
export class ThirdPartyComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }    
}
```

**thirdParty-routing.module.ts**

```
import { ThirdPartyComponent } from './thirdParty/thirdParty.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: ThirdPartyComponent
}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ThirdPartyRoutingModule { }
```

**thirdParty.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';    
import { ThirdPartyRoutingModule } from './thirdParty-routing.module';
import { ThirdPartyComponent } from './thirdParty/thirdParty.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ThirdPartyRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [ThirdPartyComponent]
})
export class ThirdPartyModule { }
```